# How to combine two data frames using merge or VLOOKUP functionality in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frame:

`df1`

```
    EmID    Employee Name
0   12345   Frist Person
1   35658   Second Person
2   65865   Third Person
3   28568   Foo Person
4   26699   Boo Person
```

`df2`

```
    Manager ID  Subordinate ID
1   28568       35658   
2   12466       12358
3   35658       12345
```

I want to merge this two data frames so that my output should looks like:

```
    Manger Name  Emp Name      
1   Foo Person  Second Person
```

I have used `df2.merge(df1, left_on = ManagerID, right_on = EmID)` but I didn't get what I am looking for. I have also try to use `for` loop still doesn't give me the desired out put. Any idea? Thanks :)

Comment: Use left_on the subordinate ID, you almost had it

Comment: @Riley I have tried this option as well but it won't give me the answer. I should get `suffix_x` and `suffix_y` but I didn't.

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about suffix, there's no common column names. Perhaps you want a "right" join (via the "how" parameter) instead of the default "left"?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all the id's in `df2` are also present in `df1`, we can set the index of `df1` to `EmpID` and select `Employee Name` column to create replacement series, then use **[`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)** to substitute the values in `df2`.

```
df3 = df2.replace(df1.set_index('EmID')['Employee Name'])
df3.columns = ['Manager name', 'Emp name']
```

---

```
>>> df3

    Manager name       Emp name
1     Foo Person  Second Person
```